# int64_t doesn't hold 13 digit integer

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-c++, c++14

My program works fine with numbers up to 10 digits, but any more digit causes it to output wrong numbers when I use hackerrank compiler. However, when I use visual studio, it doesn't output anything, but I hear something keeps rotating so fast until I close the cmd window ( maybe CPU).

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    // This program counts the "a" letters in a string (s) depending on how 
    // many iterations(numOfRepetitions) through the string
    string s;
    getline(cin, s);

    int64_t numOfRepetitions;
    cin >> numOfRepetitions;
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    int64_t i=0;
    int64_t  countA=0;    // Counting occurances of letter "a"
    for (int64_t x=0; x<numOfRepetitions; x++)
    {


        if (s[i]=='a') countA++;
        if (i==s.length()-1) i=-1;
        i++;

    }

    cout << countA << endl;
    }
    // Input that works:   s = 'a'   numOfRepetitions=1000       Output:1000
    // Input doesn't work: s = 'a'   numOfRepetitions=1000000000000 
    // Output:1410065408 ( it should be: 1000000000000 )
```

Note: I tried the suggestions in other threads using long long, int32_t, casting as double ... etc. Nothing worked

Comment: `for (int x=0; x<numOfRepetitions; x++)` If you're going to use int64_t in one place you need to use it in all places. Print the number out after you read it. If it's right there but your program doesn't work then the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: "I hear something keeps rotating so fast until I close the cmd window ( maybe CPU)" That's the fan. It's a sign that the CPU is working hard, though

Comment: `signed` integer overflow is undefined behavior. Your program very well may be rotating your CPU.

Comment: Retired Ninja -- I tried what you said switched x and i to be int64_t, but the problem still exits.

Comment: Did you ever think you're going about this the wrong way. Count the number of a's in the string once, then multiply. The number of a's isn't going to change.

Comment: I know, my input 'a' is just to simplify the problem. The program is designed for inputs like " apple", so it counts 'a'  numOfRepetitions/string.length() times

Comment: Perhaps OP is on a platform pre c++11 where `std::cin` isn't required to have `operator>>(long long&)` and is using a narrow type?

Comment: Does this not do what you need? https://ideone.com/qiA2q2 At the very least it shows that large numbers aren't necessarily a problem. Print the number out when you read it, look at it in the debugger, etc.

Comment: @johnyak What compiler are you using (including version number)? What build flags are you using?

Comment: @Retired Ninja - I am going to try the link. Thanks,

Comment: @Francois Andrieux I am using Visual Studio 2017 ( community)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux exactly, that's the problem. However, try with 'a' and 1000 for instance, and it will output 1000. Which means the algorithm doesn't cause an endless loop

Comment: @johnyak It only proves that it doesn't cause an endless loop for inputs of 1000. For example `int x; for(char y = 0; y < x; ++y);` will work for values of `x` up to `CHAR_MAX`, but it will break when the value of `x` gets too big. Possibly by being an infinite loop. Though you haven't addressed how you got the output you claim in the question.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux the output "1410065408 " I got is from HackerRank compiler. Also, I think I get your point, but can't we make INT_MAX holds 13 digits number ?

Comment: @johnyak First, when asked how your program was compiled, it meant how was your program compiled *to get the output you've claimed*. So Visual Studio 2017 has nothing to do with your result. Second, you can't change `INT_MAX` except by changing your platform. This is similar to asking to reduce the constant of gravity for your convenience. It's a physical property of the system you  occupy like `INT_MAX` is a physical property of the system your code occupies. Third, I don't know *how* the online compiler got a result, but I don't think it actually ran your code to completion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this option:

```
int main()
{
    string s;
    getline(cin, s);
    int64_t numOfRepetitions = 0;
    cin >> numOfRepetitions;
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    int64_t countA = 0;
    size_t i = 0;
    for (; i < s.size(); ++i)
        if (s.at(i) == 'a')
            ++countA;
    if (i)
        numOfRepetitions = (numOfRepetitions / i) * countA;
    std::cout << numOfRepetitions << "\n";
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Loop with x < numOfRepetitions is excess
We can to count repetitions in string and then multiply on value, how many string size fits in numOfRepetitions.
Advice:
use prefix type of increment, if it's possible.
and instead operator[] in string and other stl containers use method at.

Comment: This is an alternative solution to the code given, but doesn't address the concern of why the result wasn't correct in the first place. Secondly, `at()` is a more costly operation than `operator[]` since it performs bounds check. Prefer `at()` when the index isn't know to be within the bounds of the container and `operator[]` when it is known.

Comment: About at and operator[]. Operator[] using for debug dev. Look into some container in stl and you will see that operator[] aimed for more effective search of error.

Comment: But that's for debug builds. `at` is required to bounds check at run time but `operator[]` is not. Now, both of these are *allowed* to perform any other checks beyond those required. This is useful for developers to signal problems early. But in a release build, a reasonable standard library implementation will limit those checks to the minimum. The bounds check inserted by debug builds are completely irrelevant in selecting one of these approaches over another. See [here](https://godbolt.org/g/ho5Yuv) for a demonstration.

Comment: Actually in release operator[] have advantage over at method. And what do you think about v._Get_data()._Myfirst[index]? Does it make sense use this option for jumps in speed, if we're sure in index's correctly?

Comment: No, because those methods aren't defined by the standard. And it likely won't improve the speed at all. Does your platform expose implementation details publicly?

Comment: I've opened a [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174840/at-operator-discussion) if you want to continue talking about this instead of continuing in this comment section.

Answer (score -2):

The way you're going about solving the problem is much harder than it needs to be. You can get the answer by counting the number of 'a' characters once for the full string and whatever would be leftover and multiplying.

In these programming challenges the brute force solution is rarely the right one. Your massive loop would take too long to run.

```
long repeatedString(string s, long n)
{
    long full = n / s.size();
    long rem = n % s.size();
    long count = 0;
    long rem_count = 0;
    for (long i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (s[i] == 'a')
        {
            ++count;
            if (i < rem)
            {
                ++rem_count;
            }
        }
    }
    return count * full + rem_count;
}
```

It is worth noting that `long` is not sufficient to solve this problem in Visual Studio, you would need to change to `long long` or `int64_t`. It works on Hackerrank because they are compiling on Linux where long is 64-bits.